# indirect notification activity start (trampoline) blocked for Android version 31+

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I implemented Push Notifications in Xamarin Forms 5 following this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/notification-hubs-backend-service-xamarin-forms but when targeting Android 31 on Pixel 6a I get non silent (data) notifications but when I tap on them with my app on the background I get an error saying "indirect notification activity start (trampoline) blocked for X".

The only workaround I've found is unchecking this options on:

- Developer Settings -> Don't pop notifications on screen -> Don't pop notifications on screen:
  [image]

Is there a way to disable this in Xamarin Forms code for Android so I don't have to ask my users to enable developer options and uncheck this option?

I found this article that explains why this restriction was added for Android 12 but haven't found a way to disable this option programmatically: https://proandroiddev.com/notification-trampoline-restrictions-android12-7d2a8b15bbe2

**Update 2/7/2023:**

I read the article that @Guangyu Bai - MSFT shared and I tried sending Android test notifications from my Azure Notification Hub with the following payload:

```
{
"notification": {
    "title": "Notification Hub Test Notification",
    "body": "This is a sample notification delivered by Azure Notification Hubs.",
    "android": {
        "actions": [
            {
                "title": "test",
                "pressAction": {
                    "id": "default",
                    "launchActivity": "com.mypackage.test.MainActivity"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "data": {
        "property1": "value1",
        "property2": 42
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "Notification Hub Test Notification",
        "body": "This is a sample notification delivered by Azure Notification Hubs.",
        "data": {
            "property1": "value1",
            "property2": 42
        },
        "android": {
            "pressAction": {
                "launchActivity": "com.mypackage.test.MainActivity",
                "id": "default"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases I got the notification on my simulator but when I tapped on it, my app did not appear and got same trampoline error. Am I missing something in my test payload?

I see many articles online where they use Notifee from React using pressAction to solve this problem in Android: https://notifee.app/react-native/reference/notificationpressaction but I haven't found how that translates to Firebase Messaging Service structure.

Comment: That proandroiddev article describes what to do, to avoid the problem. Near the end, section "Update your app". Have you tried to follow those steps? If so, add that code to question. [I'm not familiar with this new Android 12 restriction; I can't help with the code.]

Answer (score 1):

You can check this link [Indirect notification activity start (trampoline) from  blocked](https://github.com/invertase/notifee/issues/250) for more information.

**Update the app**

If your app starts an activity from a service or broadcast receiver that acts as a notification trampoline, complete the following migration steps:

1. Create a PendingIntent object associated with the activity that the
   user sees after clicking the notification.
2. During the construction of the notification, use the PendingIntent object that you created in the previous step.

To identify the source of the activity, for example, to perform logging, use extra when posting notifications. For centralized logging, use ActivityLifecycleCallbacks or the Jetpack Lifecycle Watcher.

Comment: Hi @Guangyu Bai - MSFT I went to the link you shared and tried sending the pressAction property in the payload but still doesn't work. The fix has to be on the notification emitting side, which in this case it's my Azure Notification Hub which is sending the notification to Firebase Messaging Service. I posted an update on the post description. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Below replacement worked for me..

Refer: https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/issues/884#issuecomment-1386792132.

```
./android/app/build.gradle

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':react-native-notifications')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just update your library and it will work. I had the same issue, for a lower version of my 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging' then i updated it and it works.